# Using Maven API download a JAR

Tags: maven-3

In a simple java program, How can I download a JAR from a Maven repository ?
The repository can be local as well as remote ? I am using Maven 3.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @amit your use of Maven-3 is not relevant.  Your application is interested in accessing a JAR **at runtime**.  It *just so happens* that this JAR is available at a Maven repository.  Maven is a build-time tool.  It cannot help you at runtime.

So if we have interpreted your question correctly, the issue is one of formulating the URL and making an HTTP request.  Since you say the JAR is hosted by a Maven repository you know the *format* of the URL:

> http://repository.url/group_id_segments_separated_with_slashes/artifact_id/version/artifact_id-version.jar

You can take advantage of this in your program if you need to access more than one JAR in this fashion.

Answer (score -1):

define the necessary mapping for dependency tags in POM.xml and than provide repository information inside repository tags... for example..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<repository>
    <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
    <name>Java.net Snapshot Repository for Maven</name>
    <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

see more about this **[here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html)**

Comment: I am looking for an option using Maven API. As I said, I want to download the Jar in a simple java program.

Comment: In that case I dont think maven comes in picture, you simply have a resource address (URI) and want to get the resource from it, it doesnt matter whether it is a .jar, .war or any other file.. Use the Socket api to connect to the URI and than get the file... that will work in both the cases (local or from Maven repository), However if you dont have the exact URI than you need to get that before querying..

Comment: Well, i am not sure how will i get the URI for a jar in the remote repository.Any which ways, can maven give me the URL for an artifact ?